# Sample random points on the borders of the US states with sf package

Tags: r, sf

I want to sample points (latitude-longitude pairs) on borders of the US states, or points close to borders. With the following code, I am able to sample points in an example multipolygon. How can I do this on the borders instead?

```
library(sf)
nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
plot(nc$geometry[1])
plot(st_sample(nc$geometry[1], 1000))
```

Answer (score 3):

Cast the polygon into a multi-linestring and sample from that:

```
> plot(st_sample(st_cast(nc$geometry[1],"MULTILINESTRING"), 1000))
```

Comment: Cool approach! I have not seen this before.

Comment: Thanks! Does it oversamples from the line segments with longer lengths? In other words, is the expected number of points from a line segment is proportional to its length?

Comment: It distributes points uniformly along the perimeter of the feature. So if you have a triangle with sides 3,4,5 then the number of points on each side would have expected ratio of 3:4:5.